# Android- detect when the phone flips around

Tags: android, android-sensors

I want to detect when the phone is turned around that is the screen of the phone faces downward and the backside of the phone faces upward. How can i do it?

Basically i want to detect when the phone is flipped!

Answer (score 7):

Here's how I did this:

```
package com.example.accsensordemo.service;

import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.hardware.Sensor;
import android.hardware.SensorEvent;
import android.hardware.SensorEventListener;
import android.hardware.SensorManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.os.Vibrator;
import android.util.Log;

public class MotionControlService extends Service implements SensorEventListener {

    private static final String TAG = "MotionControlService";

    private float mGZ = 0;//gravity acceleration along the z axis
    private int mEventCountSinceGZChanged = 0;
    private static final int MAX_COUNT_GZ_CHANGE = 10;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        Log.d(TAG, "onStartCommand, Started: " + mStarted);

        if (!mStarted) {
            mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(SENSOR_SERVICE);

            mSensorManager.registerListener(this,
                mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER),
                SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME);

            mStarted = true;
        }
        return START_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        int type = event.sensor.getType();
        if (type == Sensor.TYPE_ACCELEROMETER) {
            float gz = event.values[2];
            if (mGZ == 0) {
                mGZ = gz;
            } else {
                if ((mGZ * gz) < 0) {
                    mEventCountSinceGZChanged++;
                    if (mEventCountSinceGZChanged == MAX_COUNT_GZ_CHANGE) {
                        mGZ = gz;
                        mEventCountSinceGZChanged = 0;
                        if (gz > 0) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "now screen is facing up.");
                        } else if (gz < 0) {
                            Log.d(TAG, "now screen is facing down.");
                        }
                    }
                } else {
                    if (mEventCountSinceGZChanged > 0) {
                        mGZ = gz;
                        mEventCountSinceGZChanged = 0;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to do this you need to register a SensorEventListener on the orientation and then add a callback to the onSensorChanged method.  The logic will probably look very similar to the compass that is implemented here: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidSensor/article.html, except that you are going to want to check to see if the value of the sensorEvent is ROTATION_0, ROTATION_90, ROTATION_180, or ROTATION_270 and act accordingly.

You will also likely need to store the previous screen orientation so you can check to see if the rotation was a 180 degree rotation or just a 90 degree rotation.

Comment: I want to detect the rotation in z-plane. This is probably for xy-plane. Anyway i found the solution [here](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/02/detect-phone-flipping.html)

Comment: Is there a way to detect it without a service and instead via <action android:name="android.intent.action.x ?

Answer (score 0):

(This is not the correct term that I'm using. I'm just trying to make my point simple)

You can image that there is a line or vector that is perpendicular to your phone screen.
**rotationMatrix[8]** is the z coordinate of that vector.

When **rotationMatrix[8]** is closer to 1, it means your phone is facing the sky and nearly parallel to the sky. And when **rotationMatrix[8]** is closer to -1, your phone is facing the ground and nearly parallel to the ground.

```
MainActivity.kt
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity(), SensorEventListener
{

    private lateinit var sensorManager: SensorManager

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)


        sensorManager = getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE) as SensorManager
        sensorManager.registerListener(
            this, 
            sensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR), 
            SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_GAME
        )
    }

    var rotationMatrix = FloatArray(9)
    var is_down = false
    override fun onSensorChanged(event: SensorEvent?)
    {
        if(event?.sensor?.type == Sensor.TYPE_ROTATION_VECTOR){
            SensorManager.getRotationMatrixFromVector(
                rotationMatrix, event.values
            )

            //you can specify how close you want your phone to be parallel to the ground. 
            //The closer it gets to 1, the more parallel it is to the ground.
            if(rotationMatrix[8] < -0.94f){ 
                if(!is_down){
                    is_down = true
                    Log.i("Sensor", "Face down")
                    //trigger some events
                }
            }

            //Here I'm telling my phone how much it needs to face up to 
            //be able to trigger the next face down event. 
            if(rotationMatrix[8] > 0.5){
                if(is_down){
                    is_down = false
                    Log.i("Sensor", "Face up")
                    //trigger some events
                }
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onAccuracyChanged(sensor: Sensor?, accuracy: Int)
    {

    }
}
```